# CRM 2011 workflow to update sharepoint document field

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to update a sharepoint document field from a CRM2011 workflow?
Thanks, Nuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  In order to do, within the context of the CRM2011 Workflow, you would need have a reference to the SharePoint url, and the item that you want to update.  you would also need to have access to the SharePoint environment.

this would have to be done in a Custom workflow assembly or an asynchronous plugin.

If you add more detail to your question, I may be able to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it could be done withou a custom assembly.